# Rebuild job type in jobs to include more options

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

The current job type is pretty bare bones right now, you have the following:

[image]

This should be rebuilt to include additional options such as:

- Full Time
- Part Time
- Internship
- Entry Level
- And maybe temporary

I believe this will help those who are simply juniors or seniors in school help to find internships.  I also think it will help those who only want to work 20-30 hours a week vs a regular 40 hour work week (Maybe they got a lot of kids, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Agree that the current functionality is quite minimal, and we'd like to support job seekers with more specific needs - whether they are a student looking for an internship or an experienced dev looking for a Senior or Lead role.

We've *just* started asking companies to provide seniority information about their job listings (e.g. Student, Junior, etc.). Our next step is to actively encourage more companies to provide this info - so that when we do ship new search filters as per your suggestion, users will have a large, accurate set of results.