# Specifying employment type of job position (full, part, internship)

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

While filling a developer story there is no field to specify a type of job position (full, part, internship, freelance, contract, etc.). The same case used to be on LinkedIn, but now there is a field «Employment type»:

[image]

This field can especially useful for those, who has several short-term positions, e.g. students, and can clarify why a person has changed couple of positions within one year.

**Important:**
In contrast to the qustion [Rebuild job type in jobs to include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312877/rebuild-job-type-in-jobs-to-include-more-options), I'm talking about the user developer story, a job type of user's position:

[image]

And not about a job type filtering option in Job preferences:

[image]